# Reverse not found with slug field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am getting error while using get_absolute_url with slug field. Have tried few suggestions which are already exist in stack but didn't worked. Can anyone help me with this please.
[Please refer this link for traceback.](http://dpaste.com/1G7Q2F9)

### models.py

Codes in models.

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
            null=True,
            blank=True, 
            width_field="width_field", 
            height_field="hieght_field")
    hieght_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    updates = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

### Views.py

codes in views.

```
def post_list(request):
    queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    context = {
        'object_list':queryset_list,
        'posts': page,
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

### urls.py

urls mapping.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<slug:slug>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

### html page

code in index.html

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
<div class="container">
<p class="card-text">{{obj.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120}}</p>
<a href="{{obj.get_absolute_url}}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
<!-- <a href="{% url 'post:detail' pk=obj.id %}"> {{obj.title}} </a> -->
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was occurring because of commented line in index.html `<a href="{% url 'post:detail' pk=obj.id %}"> {{obj.title}} </a>` after removing this line page is getting loaded perfectly and one more thing 'pk' should be replaced by slug in detail view to work detail page. `def detail(request,slug): #slug replaced pk`